# How to get present day data from Firebase timeStamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using ServerTimeStamp in my data object, now i want to retrieve only the present day data.

```js
var happycount =  admin.database().ref(`/tariq-road/happy`)
    .orderByChild('timeStamp')
    .equalTo(Date.now())
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
      var data = snapshot.numChildren()
      console.log('data:  ', data)
    })
```

How do i get the today's data?

Comment: You should store, together with the TimeStamp, the day corresponding to the TimeStamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

var happycount =  admin.database().ref(`/tariq-road/happy`)
    .orderByChild('timeStamp')
    .startAt(start.valueOf())
    .endAt(end.valueOf())
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
      var data = snapshot.numChildren()
      console.log('data:  ', data)
    })
```

Comment: this works perfectly for fetching the data belongs to the current(present) day, can you please tell me that how can i get the hourly, weekly and monthly ?